# Cut and paste using an offset

Tags: excel

I am building a web scraping tool that obtains particular data. Once the data has been extracted the next step is to summarize it into a report thus i need some guidance on the final part of the project.

I have a column (Column A) that contains the following data set

Description of product

$3000

Description of product

$5000

etc

I would like to find a value (in this case the common value is $) and cut this value  next to the description (into Column B). There could be hundreds of rows thus a loop would be required.

My initial thought is to use code that will find a value ($), then once the value is found,  cut the row and using an offset paste the value (into column B)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub test()

dim usedrows,i as integer

usedrows = activesheet.range("A" & activesheet.rows.count).end(xlup).row

for i=0 to usedrows

    if instr(range("A" & i+1),"$") <> 0 then 
                   'Checks if the looped cell has "$" sign  
        range("B" & i+1)=range("A" & i+1)
        range("A" & i+1)=""
    end if

next

end sub
```

Comment: Description can be given for snippet. Either in a sentence or by using comment lines

Comment: above code runs a forloop through column A and findds the values with "$" sign and offsets the cell to B Column particular row

Answer (score 0):

Copy ColumnA into ColumB. Delete B1 with Shift cells up. Series fil1 a column with `1` in odd rows, `2` in even, then filter to select the `2`s delete those rows and then the column of `1`s.